# mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

I just migrated a site from one domain to another domain (and another host). I made sure that all links were replaced and exported/imported my database. The migration seemed to have worked, but for some reason I am getting an error on my new domain that I did not get on my old domain (with, as far as I know, the same code).

My error is: "Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in *path* on line 84". I looked at the other StackOverflow questions that address this error, but I have not found a solution yet.

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

// 1. Create a database connection
$dbhost = 
$dbuser = 
$dbpass = 
$dbname = 
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Test if connection occurred.
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . 
    mysqli_connect_error() .
    " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
}

// 2. Perform database query
if (empty($_SESSION['order'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`) VALUES (NULL)";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    // Test if there was a query error
    if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
    }
    // 3. Use returned data (if any)
    $order_id_recent = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
    $_SESSION['order'] = $order_id_recent;
}

$size = $_POST["size"];
$paper = $_POST["paper"];
$type = $_POST["type"];
$quantity = $_POST["quantity"];

// 2. Perform database query
$query2 = "SELECT product_id FROM product WHERE product_type = '$type' AND size = '$size' AND paper = '$paper'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
// Test if there was a query error
if (!$result2) {
  die("Database query failed.");
}

// 3. Use returned data (if any)
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $product_id = $row['product_id'];
}

$order_id = $_SESSION['order'];

// 2. Perform database query
$order_id = $_SESSION['order'];

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM order_item WHERE order_id = '$order_id' AND product_id = '$product_id'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
// Test if there was a query error
if (!$result3) {
  die("Database query failed.");
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) { 
    $itemexistrows = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
}

if ($itemexistrows > 0) {
    $query4 = "UPDATE order_item SET quantity = quantity + '$quantity' WHERE product_id = '$product_id' AND order_id = '$order_id'";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($connection, $query4);
    if (!$result4) {
    die("Database query failed.");
    } else {
        echo 'The item has been added to your cart. <a class="text-red" href="viewcart.php">View your cart</a></div>.'; 
    }
} else {
    $query5 = "INSERT INTO `order_item`(`order_item_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`,`order_id`) VALUES (NULL,'$product_id','$quantity','$order_id')";
    $result5 = mysqli_query($connection, $query5);
    if (!$result5) {
    die("Database query failed.");
    } else {
        echo 'The item has been added to your cart. <a class="text-red" href="viewcart.php">View your cart</a></div>.'; 
    }
}

// 4. Release returned data
mysqli_free_result($result);

// 5. Close database connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

The weird thing is that my website still seems to work. These lines of code are part of a shopping cart module and the shopping cart seems to get updated.

Comment: Can you show the code "as-is"? Where is `//4.` located in the code? Thanks for separating but it makes it harder to help you

Comment: Hey @Martin , thanks for the prompt reply! I initially left the rest of the code out, since it is really ugly and messy (wrote it a long time ago), but I edited my post. Thanks! (Edit: it also looks like I do not try to free the results of the other queries. There probably also are a lot of ways to improve this code in general, but I am currently just hoping to solve this problem.)

Comment: Your code suffering from sql injection, I would recommend you to use sensitize the inputs you receive by using prepared statements.
https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `$_SESSION['order']` is not empty and thus $result is not set as it does not seem to be addressed inside the same if statement.

The following would almost certainly make the problem go away.

```
 if(isset($result) && $result!=null){
     // 4. Release returned data
     mysqli_free_result($result);
 }
```

Or, as suggested in comments, and probably better:

```
 if(isset($result) && is_resource($result)){
     // 4. Release returned data
     mysqli_free_result($result);
 }
```

Comment: Agreed, though I would go with `if (isset($result) && is_resource($result)) { }`

Comment: why? just use if(empty())

Comment: Wow, this would indeed make a lot of sense. Thanks @Matthew Brown (and Martin, but I can only link one user). I am going to try it now and will report back!

Comment: @Pamblam, so many ways to inspect a variable. :) We all seem to be on the same page as far as making sure that is a result to free before freeing it.

Comment: It works guys! Thanks a ton! Makes my day! I feel really stupid now, because looking back it (of course) is a very obvious mistake.

Comment: simpler is always better. empty checks all the basics in one call.

Comment: Just saw that I made the same mistake in other files as well, so it going to take some time to correct everything. It is weird that on my old domain these errors did not show up, but I am glad they did. Thanks!